# Selecting key/value pairs from API Response using Dictionary Comprehension with If/Else conditions

Tags: python, json, api, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have compiled a list of API response called `user_responses'.  This is an example of a response in the list:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "W012A3CDE",
            "team_id": "T012AB3C4",
            "name": "spengler",
            "deleted": false,
            "color": "9f69e7",
            "real_name": "spengler",
            "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "tz_label": "Pacific Daylight Time",
            "tz_offset": -25200,
            "profile": {
                "avatar_hash": "ge3b51ca72de",
                "status_text": "Print is dead",
                "status_emoji": ":books:",
                "real_name": "Egon Spengler",
                "display_name": "spengler",
                "real_name_normalized": "Egon Spengler",
                "display_name_normalized": "spengler",
                "email": "spengler@ghostbusters.example.com",
                "image_24": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
                "image_32": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
                "image_48": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
                "image_72": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
                "image_192": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
                "image_512": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
                "team": "T012AB3C4"
            },
            "is_admin": true,
            "is_owner": false,
            "is_primary_owner": false,
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_ultra_restricted": false,
            "is_bot": false,
            "updated": 1502138686,
            "is_app_user": false,
            "has_2fa": false
        },
        {
            "id": "W07QCRPA4",
            "team_id": "T0G9PQBBK",
            "name": "glinda",
            "deleted": false,
            "color": "9f69e7",
            "real_name": "Glinda Southgood",
            "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "tz_label": "Pacific Daylight Time",
            "tz_offset": -25200,
            "profile": {
                "avatar_hash": "8fbdd10b41c6",
                "image_24": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "image_32": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "image_48": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "image_72": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "image_192": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "image_512": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "image_1024": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "image_original": "https://a.slack-edge.com...png",
                "first_name": "Glinda",
                "last_name": "Southgood",
                "title": "Glinda the Good",
                "phone": "",
                "skype": "",
                "real_name": "Glinda Southgood",
                "real_name_normalized": "Glinda Southgood",
                "display_name": "Glinda the Fairly Good",
                "display_name_normalized": "Glinda the Fairly Good",
                "email": "glenda@south.oz.coven"
            },
            "is_admin": true,
            "is_owner": false,
            "is_primary_owner": false,
            "is_restricted": false,
            "is_ultra_restricted": false,
            "is_bot": false,
            "updated": 1480527098,
            "has_2fa": false
        }
    ],
    "cache_ts": 1498777272,
    "response_metadata": {
        "next_cursor": "dXNlcjpVMEc5V0ZYTlo="
    }
}
```

I would like to build a dictionary that consists of:

**1. A key that is the user's real_name.  If there is no real_name for a user then I would like to use the display_name for the user.**

For this I tried to use a ternary expression in a dictionary comprehension to deal with the if/else condition:

```
{(sub_dict['profile']['real_name'] if 'real_name' in sub_dict['profile] 
  else sub_dict['profile']['display_name']):value
  for response in user_responses
  for sub_dict in response.get('members')}
```

This seems to just default to using the display_name for each user which is not what I want.

**2. A value that is a list of all images for each user.**

For this I was thinking I could write a list comprehension that included values of all keys that started with the word "image".

```
{(key:[sub_dict['profile'][k] for k in sub_dict['profile'] if k.startswith('image')]
  for response in user_responses
  for sub_dict in response.get('members')}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to reduce for-loops into comprehensions, is to first visualize the process using a regular for loop:

```
newLst = []
for member in var["members"]:
    d = {"images": []}
    for k, v in member["profile"].items():
        if k.startswith("image"):
            d["images"].append(v)

    d["name"] = member["profile"].get("real_name")
    if not d["name"]:
        member["profile"].get("display_name")
    newLst.append(d)
```

Now, personally I would go with the above for-loop. However, your question was how you would solve it using comprehension, so here is my version of that:

```
newLst = [{"images": [v for k, v in member["profile"].items() if k.startswith("image")],
            "name": member["profile"].get("real_name", member["profile"].get("display_name"))} for member in var["members"]]
```

The big difference with both of them is that the first one is quite easy to debug, or at least follow along with the logic. While the second one is quite a bit harder to really follow along with.

results of both of them:

```
[{'images': ['https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg',
             'https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg',
             'https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg',
             'https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg',
             'https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg',
             'https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg'],
  'name': 'Egon Spengler'},
 {'images': ['https://a.slack-edge.com...png',
             'https://a.slack-edge.com...png',
             'https://a.slack-edge.com...png',
             'https://a.slack-edge.com...png',
             'https://a.slack-edge.com...png',
             'https://a.slack-edge.com...png',
             'https://a.slack-edge.com...png',
             'https://a.slack-edge.com...png'],
  'name': 'Glinda Southgood'}]
```

Comment: @Hampus_Larsson Thank you for this explanation.  I agree that a regular for loop is more readable and easier to debug.